# Is ConfigureAwait(false) needed/beneficial when awaiting async calls in Azure Functions

Tags: async-await, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, synchronizationcontext, azure-function-async

It is generally recommended to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when awaiting async calls when context is not required. Just wondering is there any benefit of using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in Azure Functions.

Do Azure Function threads have non-null `SynchronizationContext` as such it would make beneficial to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid unnecessarily capturing it and rescheduling the await continuation back on the captured `SynchronizationContext`?

It is a bit of a churn to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` at the end of every async call so prefer to avoid it for the code that runs in Azure Functions if there is no perf/or any other related gain.

Looking at the azure function host code:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/918b057707acfb842659c9dad3cef0193fae1330/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/WebScriptHostManager.cs#L181

it seems like azure function host attempts to strip out the ASP.NET SynchronizationContext before calling the azure function.

Comment: Any sources on using `ConfigureAwait(false)` for server-side code? As I remember, it's quite the opposite.

Comment: referring here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx  the recommendation is use it when you can the exception is for methods that require actual context. Nevertheles the question is specific to azure functions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Just wondering is there any benefit of using ConfigureAwait(false) in Azure Functions.

Not if your code knows it is running in that context, no.

In my Azure Functions code, I divide it up into "library-ish" code in separate library projects, and the "Azure Functions" code. I do use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the library projects, since they can (in theory, at least) be reused in other applications.

But for code that knows it is running in Azure Functions, no `ConfigureAwait(false)` is necessary. The v1 host would strip out the `SynchronizationContext`, and the v2 host runs on ASP.NET Core which doesn't have a context to begin with.

Comment: In addition don't use `ConfigureAwait` with [DurableFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview) when awaiting `ActivityFunctions` in the orchestrator function. See [https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24080](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24080).

Comment: this was very helpful. what do you mean by "The v1 host would strip out the SynchronizationContext"?

Comment: @gabe: The v1 host was an ASP.NET WebAPI process (at least for HTTP-triggered functions). But before it called into your function code, it would deliberately remove the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`.